# What does Microsoft.Phone.Logging.Logger do?

Tags: logging, windows-phone-8

i found the the class Logger in the namespace Microsoft.Phone.Logging and the assembly "Assembly Microsoft.Phone.dll, v8.0.0.0".

The functions in it are confusing as are the arguments, i can't even find it on msdn or google and it lacks xml comments.

So my question is this class intended to be used by app developers and how would i use it to log some thing?

```
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
[SecuritySafeCritical]
public static class Logger
{
    [CLSCompliant(false)]
    [SecuritySafeCritical]
    public static uint GetEventLevelAndFlags(uint subsystemOrKpiId, LogFlags logFlags, ref uint eventFlags);
    [SecuritySafeCritical]
    public static void LaunchApp_EndDuration();
    [CLSCompliant(false)]
    [SecuritySafeCritical]
    public static void YLogEvent(uint subsystemOrKpiId, uint eventCode, LogFlags logFlags, byte[] dataBlob);
    [CLSCompliant(false)]
    [SecuritySafeCritical]
    public static void YLogEvent(uint subsystemOrKpiId, uint eventCode, LogFlags logFlags, string message);
    [CLSCompliant(false)]
    [SecuritySafeCritical]
    public static void YLogEvent(uint subsystemOrKpiId, uint eventCode, LogFlags logFlags, uint dataValue);
    [CLSCompliant(false)]
    [SecuritySafeCritical]
    public static void YLogEvent(uint subsystemOrKpiId, uint eventCode, LogFlags logFlags, ulong dataValue);

    public delegate void Delegate();
}
```

Comment: Good catch, i recently implemented a logger class in my code but when i tried to use it I caught Microsoft.Phone.Logging name space too. It might be they just forgot to make it internal or hide it from others. you know after all they are developers like us

Comment: Apparently NLog is also referencing it look at this link https://github.com/nothingmn/WindowsPhone.Common/blob/master/WindowsPhone.Logging/NLogLogger.cs

Answer (score 1):

It's not meant for 3rd party developers. So you cannot use it.

Comment: What do you mean you cannot use it? Its public in static so i could make calls to it but i guess is shouldn't? Also where did you find this information?

Comment: It's doesn't do anything for 3rd party developers is what i meant. You need to change the registry before this starts doing anything and that's not something you and I can do from code :)

Comment: Again where did you find this information could you provide a link?
(Its not that i don't believe you but i would like to read more about it)